# Pattern in cyclic strings of length $n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Recently I have stumbled on the following question: "Given a cyclic string, if it is separated into substrings of the same character, and all substrings are of size $>1$, then the string is adjacent-friendly. For example, $0011220$ is adjacent-friendly while $0011221$ is not. Given the set of all cyclic strings of size $n$ consisting of only $3$ characters, how many strings inside the set are adjacent-friendly?"

After using a program in C++, I found that the answer, starting from $n=3$, is $3,15,33,69,129,255,507,1023,2049,4101\dots$ After some examining, I found the general form $a_n$: $a_n=2^n+c$ for $n\geq2$ where $c=1$ when $n\equiv1,5\pmod6$, $c=-1$ when $n\equiv2,4\pmod6$, $c=-5$ when $n\equiv3\pmod6$ and $c=5$ when $n\equiv0\pmod6$.

Since I can't use the program to generate results for higher $n$ due to the immense workload, I decided to construct a proof for the general case of $n\geq2$. However, I can't think of any way to tackle this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have just discovered that my question considered the set of non-cyclic strings. After tweaking my program for the revised problem, I found that the set of all non-cyclic strings of size $n$ and the set of all cyclic strings of size $n-1$ contains the same number of adjacent-friendly strings for $n\geq5$ except when $3|n-1$. Denoting the number of adjacent-friendly strings in the set of all non-cyclic strings of size $n$ as $a_n$, I discovered that $a_n=\displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{n-2}2a_i+3$ for $n\geq4$. [If the first substring has size $2$ to $n-2$ and consists of a different character than the second substrings, then the remaining substrings, sized $2$ to $n-2$, can be resolved to lower cases, which results in the $\displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{n-2}2a_i$ part. The $3$ comes from the remaining strings of size $n$.] It can also be rearranged into $a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$. Since $a_1=0=2^0-1$, $a_2=3=2^1+1$ and $a_3=3=2^2-1$, the general formula is thus $a_n=2^{n-1}+(-1)^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: how do you get $15$ for $n=4,$ you are counting $0011$ 4 times? meaning is $0110\neq 0011$?

Comment: @Phicar It seems that I have forgotten duplicates in this problem. For the sake of simplicity, I would be including this kind of duplicates.

Comment: FWIW: With that convention of distinguishing among the rotations, I used SageMath to confirm your formula for $n\le 18.$